# Travel to Mexico from India

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, mexico

I want to travel to Mexico from India.

I have a valid F-1 visa for USA..

Do I need to apply for any visa?
Do I need to pay any kind of fee?
Do I need to fill any form to travel to mexico

Comment: Have you tried looking this up online?  You should show at least some minimal effort when asking a question

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Embassy of Mexico in India](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/india/index.php/visas):

> ::HOLDERS OF U.S.A. CANADA, U.K. AND SCHENGEN VISAS ::
>
> Holders of any valid U.S.A., Canada, Japan, United Kingdom, Schengen visas (any nationality) or permanent residence of U.S.A., Canada, Japan, United Kingdom, Schengen, Pacific Alliance (Colombia, Peru, Chile) DO NOT require a Mexican visa to travel on business, tourism, or transit purpose for or less than 180 days as long as they present any of the mentioned documents at the point of entry.
>
> Immigration authorities keep the right to grant or deny entry to the country. Officials can request information regarding the purpose and length of your trip, as well as the means to cover your expenses while you stay in the country.

Since you have a valid F-1 visa to the US, you are not required a visa to visit Mexico for the purpose of business, tourism or transit, as long as your visit is less than 180 days and you can prove the means to support yourself (cover your expenses) during your stay.